# Graph API of several pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to know how to **get information about several pages** of facebook.
Example:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.porenvio.com
```

It is just one page.
But I would like to do something like:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.porenvio.com & http://www.google.es & ...
```

Comment: What kind of information? What do you want to do with the information?

Comment: {
  id: "http://www.porenvio.com",
  shares: 1
}

Comment: What do you mean with `shares`?

Comment: It is shares, but if you check the number of like button of this url, it is the same number. So I want the number of like button of several pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using FQL:

```
SELECT like_count, url 
  FROM link_stat 
 WHERE url = 'http://porenvio.com' 
    OR url = 'http://google.com'
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "like_count": 1, 
      "url": "http://porenvio.com"
    }, 
    {
      "like_count": 1183262, 
      "url": "http://google.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Look at the [`link_stat`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat) FQL table to find more fields: `share_count`, `total_count`, ...

Comment: It is the URL :) 
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20like_count,url%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='http://www.google.es'%20OR%20url='http://www.envio.com'